# React app not loading; whitescreen with no errors

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Hoping someone can help me as I am at my wits end trying to figure out why this isn't loading. The site compiles with no errors but then just hangs loading and whitescreen; nothing in the DOM either to point out what is wrong.

Here is the source code (https://github.com/Asutherland8219/react-portfolio)

Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
 , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Portfolio from './pages/Portfolio';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';


function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component= {Home}/>
          <Route path='/about' component= {About}/>
          <Route path='/portfolio' component= {Portfolio}/>
          <Route path='/contact' component= {Contact}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
   
    );
  }

export default App;
```

Comment: You should debug `Navbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your `Button` component.

```
 <Button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onclick}
        type={type}
        >
            {children}
        </Button>
```

You are rendering `Button` in `Button` component.

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 of your `Navbar` file says

```js
import { Button } from '../Button/Button.css';
```

I find this weird, and this error may be the reason behind this error

Comment: This wasnt the error directly but it did point me to the button.js where I had a capital typo. ie. calling Button instead of button

Thanks!

Comment: Congrats, next time try uploading the codesandbox link too. It will lead to faster and more helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={HOMEPAGE_URL} element={<App/>}/>
        ..........
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

In my case I used App as a component for the element, this will work like a recursive function and eventually kill the memory with a poup message.

I had this kind of error for the first time, where the website is loading all the time without any errors. Maybe this answer will help someone with the same problem.